# Manipular una Columna de una tabla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

en un temas anterior trate sobre un caso similar, pero en este les presento la tabla que estoy diseñando:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-header bg-primary text-center">
    <h5 style="color:white">Categoría</h5>
</div>
<table class="table table-active table-striped text-center"><!-- -->
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th >ID</th>
            <th>NOTAS</th>
            <th>RESUMEN</th>
            <th>CONTANDO<th>
            <th>OPCIONES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>
                    10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;300000000 
            </td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>
                            10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;3000000000
            </td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>
            10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;300000000 
            </td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Como pueden ver la columna *"Contando"* ocupa un gran tamaño en la tabla y quisiera su ayuda para arreglar el tamaño de esta, ya que no he encontrado una forma de solucionarlo mediante **CSS** o **Bootstrap**.

Comment: Cuando dices ayuda es qué, ¿agrandar el ancho de la columna o disminuirlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez esto te ayude; puedes incluir la propiedad `table-layout: fixed` a la tabla completa y la propiedad `word-break: break-all` a las columnas que quieras que se reduzcan

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.cont {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card-header bg-primary text-center">
  <h5 style="color:white">Categoría</h5>
</div>
<table class="table table-active table-striped text-center">
  <!-- -->
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NOTAS</th>
      <th>RESUMEN</th>
      <th>CONTANDO</th>
      <th>OPCIONES</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
      <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
      <td class="cont">
        10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;3000000000
      </td>
      <td>botones</td>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
        <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
        <td class="cont">
          10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;3000000000
        </td>
        <td>botones</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
        <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
        <td class="cont">
          10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;3000000000
        </td>
        <td>botones</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hola Ivan, gracias, le agregue las propiedades que me habías comentado y funciono, también elimine el display para que se ajustara mi tabla, gracias nuevamente

Comment: A la orden :) un gusto ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una etiqueta mal cerrada en el `thead`

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-header bg-primary text-center">
    <h5 style="color:white">Categoría</h5>
</div>
<table class="table table-active table-striped text-center"><!-- -->
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th >ID</th>
            <th>NOTAS</th>
            <th>RESUMEN</th>
            <th>CONTANDO</th><!-- Aca estaba el error -->
            <th>OPCIONES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;300000000</td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>
                            10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;3000000000
            </td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UNA NOTA</td>
            <td>PRUEBA DE UN RESUMEN</td>
            <td>
            10000000;10000000;10000000;20000000;20000000;20000000;3000000;300000000 
            </td>
            <td>botones</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema que describe en la pregunta

Comment: la pregunta no es muy concreta, y hay errores de sintaxis en las etiquetas, pense que eso lo que se necesitaba

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias con el th, no lo había visto, gracias y ya me ayudaron a resolver el problema, gracias.

Comment: No hay problema @ReinosRic